# Why does my code return random letter tokens, instead of word tokens?

Tags: python, function, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I'm an absolute beginner with Python, and I am very stuck at this part. I tried creating a function to preprocess my texts/data for topic modeling, and it works perfectly when I ran it as an individual code, but when it does not return anything when I ran it as a function. I would appreciate any help!

- The codes I'm using are very basic, and probably inefficient, but it's for my basic class, so really basic ways is the way to go for me!

codes:

```py
def clean (data):
    data_prep = []
    for data in data:
        tokenized_words = nltk.word_tokenize (data)
        text_words = [token.lower() for token in tokenized_words if token.isalnum()]
        text_words = [word for word in text_words if word not in stop_words]
        text_joined = " ".join(textwords)
        data_prep.append(text_joined)
        
    return data_prep
```

the outputs are really random like "j", ",", "i". I was using a .txt file as my data, converted from a .csv file.

edit:

I've adjusted my codes from pointed mistakes and it is now

```
def clean (data):
    data_prep = []
    for row in data:
        tokenized_words = nltk.word_tokenize (data)
        text_words = [token.lower() for token in tokenized_words if token.isalnum()]
        text_words = [word for word in text_words if word not in stop_words]
        text_joined = " ".join(text_words)
        data_prep.append(text_joined)
    return data_prep
```

results: it now returns tokenized sentences and seemingly on loop.

what is my mistake this time?

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUHtL.png)

Comment: This is clearly a mistake: `for data in data` . You want something like `for row in data`. In the loop you then should only access `row`.

Comment: Also, you typed `textwords` instead of `text_words` in the `text_joined = " ".join(textwords)` line.

Comment: Can you add your running configuration? Python Version, IDE, and the command that you trying to run this function with it.

Comment: thanks all! 
@JavadBahoosh I'm running on Python 3.8.3 on Jupyter Notebook. 

I've updated my codes but now it returns sentences tokens and it seems to be looping. I still am not sure what is it that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I will instead post this as an answer. It seems you are unnecessarily looping through all of your data twice, once in your outside for loop (`for row in data`) and then again in your list comprehensions (`[token.lower() for token in tokenized_words if token.isalnum()]`) since you are tokenizing all of the data (`nltk.word_tokenize(data)`), not just the current row. That is, your code should stop returning the same sentence multiple times if you get rid of your outermost for loop.